# How does the nn.Embedding module relate intuitively to the idea of an embedding in general?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

So, I'm having a hard time understanding `nn.Embedding`. Specifically, I can't connect the dots between what I understand about embeddings as a concept and what this specific implementation is doing.

My understanding of an embedding is that it is a smaller dimension representation of some larger dimension data point. So it maps data in `N-d` to a `M-d` latent/embedding space such that `M < N`.

As I understand it, this mapping is achieved through the learning process, as in an auto-encoder. The encoder learns the optimal embedding so that the decoder can reconstruct the original input.

So my question is, how does this relate to `nn.Embedding` module:

> *A simple lookup table that stores embeddings of a fixed dictionary and size.
> This module is often used to store word embeddings and retrieve them using indices. The input to the module is a list of indices, and the output is the corresponding word embeddings.*

does this layer "learn" a lower dimensional representation of a larger input space? Or is it something else entirely?

What I'm looking for is to take the very abstract language of the documentation to something real:

Let's say I have some input `x`. This input might be a vectorized image or maybe some sequence daily temperature data. In any case, this input `x` has 100 elements (100 days of temperature, or a 10x10 image).

How can you explain the use of `nn.Embedding()` in this case?

What does each argument mean in a real world context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, the aim when using an embedding is to reduce the dimension of your data. However, it does not *learn a lower dimensional representation of a larger input space* on its own. Starting from a random initialization you can improve this embedding through a learning process. This requires finding a suitable task to train the embedding on, I think, for another question. I believe it's called a "pretext task", where ultimately the objective is to have an accurate embedding *matrix*.

You can check the parameters of any `nn.Module` with [`.parameters()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=parameters#torch.nn.Module.parameters). *It will return an generator*.

```
<< [x for x in nn.Embedding(10, 2).parameters()][0].shape
>> torch.Size([10, 2])
```

Here, there are `10*2` parameters (i.e. `dimension_input*dimension_output` or by PyTorch's naming `num_embeddings*embedding_dims`). However *it is*, still, a lookup table: given an index it will return an embedding of size `embedding_dims`. But you these embeddings (the values of this *matrix*) can be changed.

Here's a little experiment:

```
E = nn.Embedding(10, 2)
optim = optim.SGD(E.parameters(), lr=0.01)
X = torch.randint(0, 10, size=(100,))

loss_before = E(X).mean()
loss_before.backward()
optim.step()

loss_after = E(X).mean()
```

As expected, `loss_before` and `loss_after` are different which shows `nn.Embedding`'s parameters are learnable.

---

Edit: your question comes down to, "how do I encode my data?".

For those examples you gave precisely:

> Let's say I have some input x. This input might be a vectorized image or maybe some sequence daily temperature data. In any case, this input x has 100 elements (100 days of temperature, or a 10x10 image).

You can't use a `nn.Embedding` to *solve* these cases. Embedding layers are different to a reduction matrix. The latter can be used to reduce **every single vector of dimension `d`** into dimension `n` where `n<<d`. The prerequisite to using an embedding layer is having a finite dictionnary of possible elements. For example, you might want to represent a word with a vector of size `n` then you would use a embedding of `nb_possible_words x n`. This way, for any given word in the dictionnary the layer will produce the corresponding `n`-size vector.

As I said in the comments below, `num_embeddings` is the number of unique elements you are working with and `embedding_dim` is the size of the embedding, i.e. the size of the output vector.

`nn.Embedding` is usually used at the head of a network to cast encoded data into a lower dimensionality space. It won't solve your problem by magically reducing your dimensions.

If you have a sequence of temperatures you want to analyse. You could encode each temperature into a one-hot-encoding. But this vector representation might be very large (depending on the number of different temperatures). Using an embedding layer would allow to reduce the size of these vectors. This is important when the aim is to analyse the data with a RNN any other MLP for that matter. Since the bigger your input size, the more paramaters you will have!

Comment: Yes, I do understand that learning doesn't occur without training. My question is more about how to relate the language of the documentation to the conceptual understanding of what an embedding is. The docs language is very abstract and unhelpful.

Comment: It is the question you asked: "does this layer 'learn' a lower dimensional representation of a larger input space? Or is it something else entirely?". So I don't quite understand what you are missing with `nn.Embedding`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to understand the language of the documentation in the context of what an embedding is conceptually. For example, the first argument of the constructor is:

"num_embeddings (int) – size of the dictionary of embeddings". Well what does that mean with relationship to the fact that an embedding is lower dimensional representation of data in a higher dimension space?

Comment: [wait I'm reading your edit ;) ] I'm affraid I don't understand what's missing. The documentation clearly states how the embedding layer works. But to give you some clarifications: it's purpose is to cast high dimensional data into lower dimension. I think what you're referring to by 'embedding' is the actual resulting low-dimensional vector. So it is equivalent to output of a `nn.Embedding` layer.

Comment: `num_embeddings` is the number of unique elements you would like to embed (i.e. the number of elements in your high-dimensional space). Each one will have an index in the embedding layer (i.e. the reduction matrix). Each word/vector in your dictionnary has to have a unique index! Given an index, layer `E` will output the corresponding embedding (this output will just be a vector of size `dimension_output`) by using its lookup table, nothing more.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify my question. I'm hoping that the addition to the bottom of my question will help you understand what I'm asking.